# Nesting in EL conditional operator

Tags: jsf-2, el, conditional-operator

I am trying to do nesting inside the conditional operator of a Facelets page.

```
<h:outputText value="#{login.loginModel.selectedTab=='1'?bundle.idea:(login.loginModel.selectedTab=='2'?bundle.question:(login.loginModel.selectedTab=='3'?bundle.bug:bundle.thanks))} #{bundle.id} &lt;b&gt;#{detail.detailModel.postDetail.id}&lt;/b&gt;&lt;hr/&gt;" escape="false"/>
```

However, it returns an error that the EL expression isn't correct. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: Works fine for me. What EL impl/version? What exception exactly?

Comment: Unrelated, your code could be more readable.

Comment: It was showing an error in parsing the el expression however I figured out the mistake and its working now. Thanks for your responses.